# Exception by BufferedOutputStream.flush: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, bufferedoutputstream

An app gets the following exception **occasionally**:

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)' on a null object reference
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:85)
```

from:

```
bufferedOutputStream.flush()
```

I assume it is not because bufferedOutputStream is null, but something else.  If may understanding correct?  If so, what is it?

```
bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArrayData, iOffset, iDataLength);
bufferedOutputStream.flush();
```

Comment: How are you creating `bufferedOutputStream`? It would appear that whatever `OutputStream` you are supplying to the `BufferedOutputStream` constructor is `null`.

Comment: It is created like this: new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream).   I will check outputStream and  report back.   It may take a while because it happens only occasionally.

Comment: So `outputStream` is null only occasionally. Duplicate.

Comment: I am yet to confirm it.   It would be a bit surprising if BufferedOutputStream takes a null OutoutStream in its constructor without throwing an exception.